# How to produce JSON logs with numeric values in Java web application?

Tags: json, logging, log4j, log4j2

I need to add JSON logs for a Spring Boot application, which is configured to use SLF4J with Log4j2 for logging. Apart from the regular log event attributes like message, logging level, timestamp, logger name etc, there could be attributes related to HTTP calls, e.g. request method, request URI, response status code, request/response body size, processing time and so on. The idea is to ingest such log events into ElasticSearch or OpenSearch and run queries using those attributes.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to add the numeric values into the resulting JSON logs as numbers and not as strings. In my case, I need this for the following attributes: HTTP response status code, request/response body size and processing time. The example output should look like this:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-05-25T19:56:23.370Z",
  "log.level": "INFO",
  "message": "Some message",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo",
  "http.request.method": "POST",
  "url.path": "/some/path",
  "http.request.bytes": 1024,
  "http.response.status_code": 200,
  "http.response.duration_ms": 142
}
```

---

In my first attempt, I put all those attributes into a ThreadContext (MDC) using SLF4J's `org.slf4j.MDC.putCloseable(String key, String val)` method and then configured Log4j with [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) with my XML configuration looking like below:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This resulted in the required JSON structure, but all numeric values were serialized as strings:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-05-25T19:56:23.370Z",
  "log.level": "INFO",
  "message": "Some message",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo",
  "http.request.method": "POST",
  "url.path": "/some/path",
  "http.request.bytes": "1024",
  "http.response.status_code": "200",
  "http.response.duration_ms": "142"
}
```

I needed either: a) to configure JSON Template Layout so that it would convert/parse certain attributes into numbers before serializing them into JSON, or b) to add the attributes in question into a ThreadContext (MDC) as numbers and also to prevent them from being stringified before the serialization.

I wasn't able to find anything in Log4j documentation that would help with option a), so I decided to explore further the option b).

Since SLF4J API only allows `java.util.String` values to be put into MDC, I needed to use Log4j API directly. Apparently, there is a ThreadContextMap implementation in Log4j that allows to put any Object values in there. To use it, I needed to add `log4j2.threadContextMap=org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.CopyOnWriteSortedArrayThreadContextMap` property into my `log4j2.system.properties` file, and then use `org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ObjectThreadContextMap.putValue(String key, V value)` method to put the values into it:

```java
ObjectThreadContextMap threadContextMap = (ObjectThreadContextMap) ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap();
threadContextMap.putValue("http.response.status_code", responseStatusCode);
```

In addition to that, all ThreadContext (MDC) values are stringified in the `EcsLayout.json` provided by Log4j out of the box:

```json
...
  "labels": {
    "$resolver": "mdc",
    "flatten": true,
    "stringified": true
  },
...
```

I was not sure if it is possible to override specific values in the template layouts via XML configuration, so I just created a copy of `EcsLayout.json` file with `stringified` property disabled and used it in my Log4j XML configuration instead.

All this gives me the result I wanted, but this whole solution seems quite awkward and cumbersome. Is there any more elegant and straightforward way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** Your assessment and approach is right. You don't need to clone the entire `EcsLayout.json`, you can override `labels` as an *additional field*. Note that [Elasticsearch always serializes MDC to strings](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-java/blob/main/ecs-logging-core/src/main/java/co/elastic/logging/EcsJsonSerializer.java#L194).

#### Non-string MDC values

SLF4J indeed does not allow non-string values in the MDC. The Log4j implementations do, but Log4j API does not expose this, yet. Hence, the ugly casting needed. There is [LOG4J2-1648](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1648) to address this issue. (**Disclaimer:** I am the author of JTL and the Apache Logging Services (log4j, log4cxx, etc.) PMC chair. You can hire me to improve Log4j, including implementing the cited ticket.)

#### Overriding a field loaded from a JTL template

This is the very first subject explained in [the additional fields documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#additional-event-template-fields):

```xml
<JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json">
  <EventTemplateAdditionalField
       key="labels"
       format="JSON"
       value='{"$resolver": "mdc", "flatten": true}'/>
</JsonTemplateLayout>
```

But as I mentioned earlier, even though it is not explicitly stated in the [`labels` specification](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/8.11/ecs-base.html#field-labels), [Elasticsearch serializes MDC values into strings](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-java/blob/main/ecs-logging-core/src/main/java/co/elastic/logging/EcsJsonSerializer.java#L194).